# Assign selectInput choices from R list in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have a problem! I have a directory with a list of files (all with same extension `.hist`). I want to plot histograms for all of these files (I can do this part), but I then want to be able to select any of the histograms from a drop down menu in shiny, without explicitly writing the "choices". That is to say, I want the choices to be dynamic and based on the `.hist` files read in...

Let's say I have 5 samples and their corresponding `.hist` files:

```
A.hist
B.hist
C.hist
D.hist
E.hist
```

First I load in all my `.hist` files:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

temp = list.files(pattern="*.hist")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.table(temp[i]))
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.table)
```

Then I want to output histograms for each of the `.hist` files:

```
plot_histogram <- function(x) {
  
  x <- ggplot(x, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
    ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth")
  
}

lapply(myfiles, plot_histogram)
```

BUT, I want a shiny app, whereby I can select from all my samples (A, B, C, D or E) and it'll generate the plot. I do not want to explicitly state, `A, B, C, D, E` as choices, as the the number of `.hist` files may change. The app will take a download of .hist files per batch run, so I need it to iterate through the files present in the directory.

Here's what I have...

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Histogram QC"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      ##ISSUE IS HERE, I do not want to use choices = c("A.hist", "B.hist" etc)
       selectInput("histo", "Select sample",
                  choices = c()
      ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("histograms")
  )
))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$histograms <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(input$histo, aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
      ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth") 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want `selectInput` to take in all the options from `myfiles`... which would equate to be (A.hist, B.hist etc) without naming them explicitly. Is that possible?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

#load in coverage.hist files
coverage_hist = list.files(pattern="*_coverage.hist")

#load as separate df objects
for (i in 1:length(coverage_hist)) assign(coverage_hist[i], read.table(coverage_hist[i]))

#load as list of dfs
hist_files = lapply(coverage_hist, read.table)

#Add names to list
names(hist_files) = coverage_hist

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Histogram QC"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("histo", "Select sample",
                  choices = coverage_hist
      )),
      mainPanel(
        plotOutput("histograms")
      )
    ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$histograms <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(get(input$histo), aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
      ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth") 
  })

#or using list
#output$histograms <- renderPlot({ 
   # ggplot(hist_files[[input$histo]], aes(V2, V5)) + geom_col() + xlim(0,500) + ylim(0,0.01)+
     # ylab("Proportion") + xlab("Read Depth") 
#  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```